# Custom Google Maps marker HTML

Tags: html, css, google-maps, maps

I'm embedding a Google maps style footer, with a div overlay containing things like working hours, or contact info. I'm also trying to incorporate a custom location marker, something like this:

[image: Example marker]

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Google offers a complete and detailed guide on styling an embedded maps.  This includes custom markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays 

This may also help: https://mapbuildr.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the google maps API, you can use this code.

```
function initMap() {
  // store latitude and longitude for map and marker
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  // create a map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  // create a custom marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    icon: 'my-image.png'
  });
}
```

This code created a myLatLng variable which stores the Latitude and Longtitude, it then creates a map object. I assume you already have that setup if you have a map in your site.

The code then declared a marker, using the same latitude and longitude at the map via the `position` property, setting a title via the `title` property and choosing the image that will be used on the marker via the `icon` property.

This function was initially lifted straight from the documentation found at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers